# No such module 'Cocoa' in UiTabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, xcode6

I created a new file in `xcode 6` with the `UiTabBarController` template.

It generated this code:

```
import Cocoa

class BottomBarController: UiTabBarController {

}
```

This is giving me the error: `No such module 'Cocoa'`

Whats wrong here? I haven't changed anything from what `Xcode` generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you created the file you had OS X selected, not iOS. Changing `Cocoa` to `UIKit` should fix it. If that doesn't work, delete the file & create it again but be sure you are creating an iOS Cocoa Touch class not Cocoa class.